# bootstrap 4 icon inside input not works

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make icon in left side inside of input but it not show me.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class='form-grpup has-feedback'>
          <span class='"glyphicon glyphicon-search'> </span>
            <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Search"/>
          </div>
```

Comment: Please read the documentation http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/

Answer (score 0):

Glyphicon in bootstrap 4 are not inside again...you must copy fonts folder from boot3 and after add this code in your bootstrap.css...bye...

https://gist.github.com/planetoftheweb/5d75a1ad45eb3059710747a3695fc068